# SQLite data migration from Version 0 to 1

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Previously i have created a database using `db = openOrCreateDatabase("LOCALTILEDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);` which is creating a database with version '0'.

In the next version of the application I am using SQLiteOpenHelper class, In which OnUpgrade method is showing the error called, database version cannot be '0'.

So please anyone help me to migrate data from my 0 version of DB to Version 1 DB.

Comment: I haven't fully looked into this as yet, but what you could do, is open your current database (using the getWriteableDatabase()) and then run, using the `execSQL` method, the following SQL `PRAGMA user_version = 1`. However it's then how to handle changing the version number. I'll probably have a little play to see what I can come up with.

Comment: As per answer, you don't need to use PRAGMA to change the version.

Answer (score 0):

In your class which extends with  SQLiteOpenHelper, pass  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) on default constructor. For ex.

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb";


public MyDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase aSqLiteDatabase) {

}  @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you did was to code a version of 0 that was passed via the super  e.g. :-

```
public static final int DBVERSION = 0;

public SO46316125DBHlpr(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
}
```

This will result in the exception  which includes `Version must be >= 1, was 0`

e.g. :-

```
09-20 21:16:40.631 1840-1840/mjt.soqanda E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: mjt.soqanda, PID: 1840
                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mjt.soqanda/mjt.soqanda.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version must be >= 1, was 0
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Version must be >= 1, was 0
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:99)
                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.<init>(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:77)
                                                               at mjt.soqanda.SO46316125DBHlpr.<init>(SO46316125DBHlpr.java:23)
```

However, simply coding a non-zero, positive version, that is passed into the super method, will then result in that version being used.

---

e.g. I've set a DB to be version 0 (using `PRAGMA user_version=0`, followed by `PRAGMA user_version` (retrieves version) and have :-

```
09-20 21:29:35.117 19172-19172/? D/DBVERSION: The Database User Version is 1
09-20 21:29:35.118 19172-19172/? D/CHGDBVERSION: Attempting to alter DB Version from 1 to new version 0
09-20 21:29:35.152 19172-19172/? D/CHGDBVERSION: DB Version changed successfully, DB Version is now 0
```

I then use version 100:-

```
public static final int DBVERSION = 100;

public SO46316125DBHlpr(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
}
```

So this jumps directly to version 100 (onUpgrade method is empty) as per :-

```
09-20 21:35:45.344 27937-27937/mjt.soqanda D/DBVERSION: The Database User Version is 100
```

Of course 1 works as well.

---

For testing/producing the above I used the following methods :-

```
public void showDBVersion() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA user_version",null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.d("DBVERSION","The Database User Version is " + csr.getString(0));
    }
}


public int alterDBVersion(SQLiteDatabase db, int fromversion, int toversion) {

    int current_version = -1;
    int changed_version = -1;

    Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA user_version;",null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        current_version = csr.getInt(0);
    } else {
        Log.d("CHGDBVERSION","Unable to get the current version.");
        return current_version;
    }

    if (current_version == fromversion) {
        Log.d("CHGDBVERSION","Attempting to alter DB Version from " +
                Integer.toString(fromversion) +
                " to new version " +
                Integer.toString(toversion)
        );
        db.rawQuery("PRAGMA user_version=" + Integer.toString(toversion) + ";",null); //NOTE 1
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA user_version=" + Integer.toString(toversion) + ";");
    }

    csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA user_version;",null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        changed_version = csr.getInt(0);
    } else {
        Log.d("CHGDBVERSION","Unable to get the new/changed version.");
        return -2;
    }
    if (current_version != fromversion || changed_version != toversion) {
        Log.d("CHGDBVERSION",
                "DB Version was not changed as requested. Version is now " +
                        Integer.toString(changed_version));
        return -3;
    } else {
        Log.d("CHGDBVERSION","DB Version changed successfully, DB Version is now " +
        Integer.toString(changed_version));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note 1 does not work have to use execSQL as per [Android: PRAGMA statements that set data don't work](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-3380)

With the following code in the MainActivity

```
    SO46316125DBHlpr dbhlpr = new SO46316125DBHlpr(this);
    dbhlpr.showDBVersion();
    dbhlpr.alterDBVersion(dbhlpr.getWritableDatabase(),1,0);
```

Obviously varying the parameters (first is the version to change from so the current version must match it, and the second is the version to change to, if the first is matched). The above example will change version 1 to version 0.